SharePoint Export to Excel removes spaces
I have a Glossary I created as a List in SharePoint in Microsoft 365. There are nearly 1000 entries, and I used SharePoint's "classic experience" to add links between terms.
It looks and works great, until I export the List to Excel. For some reason, every word in the definitions that contains a link has no space in front of it, so it is smooshed into the word before it.
For example, if the definition says this: "A container for a solution in the Agile methodology," and both "solution" and "Agile" are linked to other terms, the same sentence comes over to Excel as
this: "A container for asolution in theAgile methodology."
It also is doing crazy things with font sizes in the definitions - randomly blowing up a word or two to 14 or 16 pt font, when everything else is 10 pt in the Excel file and the definitions content in the List are all controlled by div classes.
Any idea why this weird stuff is happening? Thanks in advance for any insights!
